# submit any of the text of the selected option using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the form is submit I can only get the number assigned to the value. I want to submit any of the texts that is between the `select` options.

For example, when I select `Bird` and `Dove` I want to receive `Bird` and `Dove` not `3` and `3`

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
  <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Cars</option>
    <option value="2">Phones</option>
    <option value="3">Birds</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="1">Benz</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>
    <option value="2">iPhone</option>
    <option value="2">Samsung</option>
    <option value="2">Motorola</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="3">Dove<option>
  </select><br>
  <label>Postal code</label>
  <input type="number" name="zipcode" placeholder="postal code">
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submit the `value` of the selected option is sent. The problem is because you're using this value to match the child `option` elements to the parent.

To fix this you need to use `value` as it was intended, ie. to hold the value you want to send to the server when the form is submit, and use a different method for grouping the `option` elements between `select`. I'd suggest using a `data` attribute for this instead, like this:

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if (!$(this).data('options')) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  
  var category = $(this).find('option:selected').data('category');
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('category') == category;
  });
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
  <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option data-category="0" value="">-Select-</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Phones">Phones</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Birds">Birds</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option data-category="0" value="Cars">-Select-</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="Benz">Benz</option>
    <option data-category="1" value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="iPhone">iPhone</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option data-category="2" value="Motorola">Motorola</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Eagle">Eagle</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Hawk">Hawk</option>
    <option data-category="3" value="Dove">Dove</option> <!-- note I fixed your typo here, missing / -->
  </select><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value from **number** to **text**.

**example**

```html
<option value="Hawk">Hawk</option>
<option value="Dove">Dove<option>
```

Done!

Comment: This fixes the immediate problem, but look at what it breaks in the rest of the code

Comment: It is never needed or beneficial to repeat an option's text as its `value` declaration -- just omit the `value` declaration and everything will work as intended.